# What happens when I call hist(x) with a matrix input?

Tags: r, syntax, histogram

I can use hist(x) to plot a histogram of a variable in R. Oddly, this works even when the input x is a matrix, even though the documentation says it should be a vector. What is going on here?

Comment: R isn’t terribly consistent in this, but in reality most types of value in R *are* vectors — with very, very few exceptions. So even types for which `is.vector(x)` is `FALSE` are actually vectors. For many purposes, a matrix *is a vector* with additional attributes (namely, dimensions). So when the documentation says that a function requires a vector, this (unfortunately!) isn’t very specific.

Answer (score 3):

The code for `hist.default` starts as this:

```
function (x, breaks = "Sturges", freq = NULL, probability = !freq,
    include.lowest = TRUE, right = TRUE, density = NULL, angle = 45,
    col = NULL, border = NULL, main = paste("Histogram of", xname),
    xlim = range(breaks), ylim = NULL, xlab = xname, ylab, axes = TRUE,
    plot = TRUE, labels = FALSE, nclass = NULL, warn.unused = TRUE,
    ...)
{
    if (!is.numeric(x))
        stop("'x' must be numeric")
    xname <- paste(deparse(substitute(x), 500), collapse = "\n")
    n <- length(x <- x[is.finite(x)])
```

the piece `x <- x[is.finite(x)]` not only removes infinite and NA values but also effectively coerces `x` to a vector, be it vector, matrix or array.

So matrices and arrays are coerced to vectors.

The help for this function does not specify it, which is a flaw.